# Error installing package (Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.) (Laravel admin package - Voyager)

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php, voyager

i want to install a laravel admin package -voyager version 1.3 ,so when i run this cmd `$ composer require tcg/voyager` i got this error always  , is about the file composer.json

```
Using version ^1.3 for tcg/voyager
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - tcg/voyager v1.3.0 requires intervention/image ^2.4 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1].
    - tcg/voyager v1.3.1 requires intervention/image ^2.4 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1].
   - intervention/image 2.4.3 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.4.2 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.

    - Installation request for tcg/voyager ^1.3 -> satisfiable by tcg/voyager[v1.3.0, v1.3.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\AppServ\php7\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

and this is the file composer.json :
    {

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "type": "project",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "laravel"
        ],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.2",
            "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
            "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
            "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
            "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
            "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
        },
        "config": {
            "optimize-autoloader": true,
            "preferred-install": "dist",
            "sort-packages": true
        },
        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "dont-discover": []
            }
        },   ..
```

, Do you know how to solve that? my laravel version : 6.12

Comment: Out of curiosity: have you read that error message? It tells you pretty straight what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling `php_fileinfo.dll` in you `php.ini` file. Just remove `;` from the below line and restart your server

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```